# converting macro velocity to freemarker

Tags: macros, freemarker, velocity

I have this macro in velocity trying to convert it to a `freeMarker` template:

```
    #macro(headerRow $yard $yardName)
    <tr><td class="header" colspan="6">Call List - $yard - $yardName</td></tr>
#end
```

In `freeMaker`, I had:

```
<#macro(headerRow ${yard} ${yardName})>
    <tr><td class="header" colspan="6">Call List - ${yard} - ${yardName}</td></tr>
</#macro>
```

At the first line it will not like it, not sure where the close tag has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freemarker [macro](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html) first line shouldn't have special characters (as `$`).

In your case:

```
 <#macro headerRow yard yardName>
<tr><td class="header" colspan="6">Call List - ${yard} - ${yardName}</td></tr>
```

> for example <#macro "foo~bar">.... Note that this string literal does not expand interpolations (as "${foo}").

Comment: Thanks! also how would I use the macro? Do I need to user {} ?    Like in velocity #headerRow($form.yard $form.yardName)

Comment: @Samarland call `<@headerRow  yard="b" yardName="a"/>`

Comment: what adding the a & b?

Comment: @Samarland it's just example of prarmeters values

Comment: Thanks! I got all what I need!